# Prolongation of the solution

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

> Given
> $$\begin{cases}y'=2(3x^2-1)\sqrt{y} \\y(1)=9 \end{cases}$$

the exercises asks me to determine if the solution can be extended to all $\mathbb R$.
The function $f(x,y):=2(3x^2-1)\sqrt{y}$ is $\mathcal C^{\infty}(\mathbb R\times [0,+\infty))$ and the solution of the Cauchy's problem is, assuming $y\ne 0$
$$y(x)=\pm (x^3-x+3)^2 (\text{only the positive solution is acceptable}).$$
The solution is defined in the most wide interval in which the function is not zero, so for a negative $x_{\alpha}$, the solution is defined in $(x_{\alpha},+\infty)$.
The derivative is also zero in $x_{\alpha}$ zero, since $y'(x_{\alpha})=2(3x_{\alpha}^2-1)\sqrt{y(x_{\alpha})}=0$, hence we can extend the solution with the constant function $y\equiv 0$.
Is the prolongation unique? I think that there are infinite possible prolongations of the solution to all $\mathbb R$, but I'd like to formalize this.

Comment: Why is the continuation with the zero function not admissible? The equation is first order, so first order continuity should be the goal?

Comment: The condition $y(1)=9$ is not satisfied by the zero function, so it can't be a solution for the Cauchy's problem

Comment: I do not understand, $y(x)=\max(0,x^3-x+3)^2$ goes through that point.

Comment: You mean the functions glued together, right? I wanted to say that if we would have had the generic initial condition $y(1)=\alpha$, then the function $y\equiv 0$ would represent a solution for the Cauchy problem in all $\mathbb R$.

Comment: It is a $C^1$ function that satisfies the differential equation. The solutions are not unique along $y=0$, solutions can branch off at any time where the factor $(3x^2-1)$ is positive.

Comment: Now I edit my question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118553/discussion-between-greg-and-lutz-lehmann).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a little less intuitive to think in negative time direction than in positive, as one has to also mentally reverse the vector fields.

We know $x_α=-\frac2{\sqrt3}\cosh(u_α)<-1<-\frac1{\sqrt3}$, where $\cosh(3u_α)=\frac{27\sqrt3}{2}$. Thus the factor $3x^2-1$ and with it the vector field is positive for $x<x_α$, $y>0$. Solutions in that region grow away from the zero axis, can not return there. Or seen in the other direction, the solution set contracts towards the zero axis when looking into the past, so once zero is reached, there is no getting away.

On the other hand, the solution segments with positive values are unique, so there is no other path to reach the initial point than the one you computed.

Comment: The graph of the solution would be described by $$y(x):=\begin{cases}(x^3-x+3)^2 && x>x_{\alpha}\\0 && x\le x_{\alpha} \end{cases} (?)$$

Comment: Yes. Or equivalently and shorter, as I already wrote, $y(x)=\max(0,x^3−x+3)^2$.